# Arrange pivot row labels in fixed order

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I would like to have my macro arrange the row labels of my pivot in a certain order (by quarter/year - see code below). Some data that the macro will be run on will not include any all row labels as per the code below - that's why I inserted the "on error goto 0".

Unfortunately, only some of the data/quarters are arranged in the right order using the code below.

Can anyone help in showing what am I doing wrong?

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Issue Quarter")
On Error Resume Next
    .PivotItems("Q1 2014").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("Q2 2014").Position = 2
    .PivotItems("Q3 2014").Position = 3
    .PivotItems("Q1 2015").Position = 4
    .PivotItems("Q2 2015").Position = 5
    .PivotItems("Q3 2015").Position = 6
    .PivotItems("Q4 2015").Position = 7
    .PivotItems("Q1 2016").Position = 8
    .PivotItems("Q2 2016").Position = 9
    .PivotItems("Q3 2016").Position = 10
    .PivotItems("Q4 2016").Position = 11
On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

If at least one item is missing (and any items which come later are present), then the order of your code will mess up...

While this code it not the way I would do it, it should be self explaining ;)

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Issue Quarter")
  Dim i As Byte
  i = 1
  On Error Resume Next
  .PivotItems("Q1 2014").Position = i
  If Err.Number Then Err.Clear Else i = i + 1
  .PivotItems("Q2 2014").Position = i
  If Err.Number Then Err.Clear Else i = i + 1
  .PivotItems("Q3 2014").Position = i
  If Err.Number Then Err.Clear Else i = i + 1
  .PivotItems("Q1 2015").Position = i
  If Err.Number Then Err.Clear Else i = i + 1
  .PivotItems("Q2 2015").Position = i
  If Err.Number Then Err.Clear Else i = i + 1
  .PivotItems("Q3 2015").Position = i
  If Err.Number Then Err.Clear Else i = i + 1
  .PivotItems("Q4 2015").Position = i
  If Err.Number Then Err.Clear Else i = i + 1
  .PivotItems("Q1 2016").Position = i
  If Err.Number Then Err.Clear Else i = i + 1
  .PivotItems("Q2 2016").Position = i
  If Err.Number Then Err.Clear Else i = i + 1
  .PivotItems("Q3 2016").Position = i
  If Err.Number Then Err.Clear Else i = i + 1
  .PivotItems("Q4 2016").Position = i
  On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

A less obvious way (which is shorter, but does the same):

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Issue Quarter")
  Dim i As Byte, x As Variant: i = 1
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each x In Array("Q1 2014","Q2 2014","Q3 2014","Q1 2015","Q2 2015","Q3 2015","Q4 2015","Q1 2016","Q2 2016","Q3 2016","Q4 2016")
    .PivotItems(x).Position = i
    If Err.Number Then Err.Clear Else i = i + 1
  Next
  On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

**EDIT**

Just for showing a way to do it without errors ;) (it will sort all pivot items which look like "Q? ????" with lowest quarter in the earliest year first and the last year with highest quarter last / -> Q1 2013 ... Q4 2013, Q1 2014 ... Q4 2016)

```
Dim x, y() As Double, i As Long
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Issue Quarter")
  ReDim y(1 To .PivotItems.Count)
  For Each x In .PivotItems
    If x Like "Q? ????" Then
      i = i + 1
      y(i) = Right(x, 4) & "." & Mid(x, 2, 1)
    End If
  Next
  If i = 0 Then Exit Sub
  ReDim Preserve y(1 To i)
  For i = 1 To UBound(y)
    x = Application.Small(y, i)
    x = "Q" & Right(x * 10, 1) & " " & Int(x)
    .PivotItems(x).Position = i
  Next
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply reverse the order and put each item in at the first position:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Issue Quarter")
    On Error Resume Next
    .PivotItems("Q4 2016").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("Q3 2016").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("Q2 2016").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("Q1 2016").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("Q4 2015").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("Q3 2015").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("Q2 2015").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("Q1 2015").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("Q4 2014").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("Q3 2014").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("Q2 2014").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("Q1 2014").Position = 1
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
```

BTW, you seemed to have missed out Q4 2014.